# C# Delegates and Function Calls

Tags: c#, function, delegates

Assuming I have this function:

```
Func<string> fs = () => "test";
var st = fs();
```

I want to simplify this to:

```
var st = (()=> "test")();
```

It seems however that I can't define the function and then instantly invoke it. Is this possible in another way?

This is possible:

```
var st = (new Func<string>(() => "test"))();
```

But very messy.

To clarify is it possible to define an anonymous function without have to specify the delegate type being used, i.e. is there a way to get the compiler to infer the types directly from the function?

Comment: And why would you want to do this?

Comment: This becomes useful for for wrapping more complex functions where I want to temporarily scope some variables in the function call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the type somehow. Others have shown how to do this inline.

There is another possibility: Create a helper method. Because the parameter of the method is defined, you don't have to define the type yourself when calling the method.

```
static class Execute
{
    public static T Func<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        return func();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var st = Execute.Func(() => "test");
```

Comment: I prefer this because it has less curved brackets. Do you know if the compiler will eventually be able to support functions without the type deceleration?

Comment: @MichaelEdwards: I have no idea what the compiler is going to support. I could imagine that it would be possible to implement this - afaik F# already has this - but that doesn't mean that it actually will be implemented at some point. BTW: You don't need the generic type parameter when calling `Func` (see updated usage).

Answer (score 3):

Just cast the expression to the correct type like this:

```
var st = ((Func<string>) (() => "test"))();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically compiler does not know whether it's an expression tree or an anonymous method. You want the latter, you have to specify a type somewhere along the way.

If you don't want to cast the lambda inline, you should go with helper methods:

```
static TResult call<TResult>(Func<TResult> f)
{
    return f();
}
static TResult call<T1, TResult>(Func<T1,TResult> f, T1 arg1)
{
    return f(arg1);
}
static TResult call<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> f, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
    return f(arg1, arg2);
}
// and so on...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(call(() => "test"));
}
```